# Создание регулярки из букв

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

Регулярка должна состоять только из русских букв, только ОДНА буква может быть заглавной, без пробелов и других знаков

```
deep_ocean = '''Окунь форель щУка Щука ФОрель Форель'''
import re
nemo_pattern = '([А-Я][а-я])'
matched_at_begin = re.match (nemo_pattern, deep_ocean)
print (matched_at_begin)
```

выводит вот это
<re.Match object; span=(0, 2), match='Ок'>

Что это значит?

Comment: `nemo_pattern = r'\b([А-Я][а-я]+)\b'`? :)

Comment: это что-то уже близкое :) но он выводит только те слова, где заглавная буква первая ( Окунь, Форель), а а по моему заданию, заглавная буква может стоять где-угодно ( например щУка)

Answer (score 2):

это значит тип данных, который возвращает `re.match ()`. Означает, что найдена подстрока, удовлетворяющая регулярке. `span=(0, 2)` означает, что найденная подстрока начинается на позиции 0 (т.е. первый символ), заканчивается на позиции 1 (т.е. второй символ). Сама подстрока указана в match.

Чтобы вывести саму найденную подстроку нужно использовать

```
print (matched_at_begin.group())
```

Comment: спасибо большущее! у меня явно что-то не так с регуляркой, она не соответсвует условиям ( только буквы, только одна заглавная). как можно было бы исправить?

Comment: да. Она не соответствует. match ищет только с начала строки. Поэтому находится только "Ок", потому что все остальное уже не начало строки. Используйте findall(), ну и регулярку придется подправить.

Answer (score 1):

А как насчет такого?

- `\b` используется для определения границ
- `*` - указывает на от 0 до бесконечного количества совпадений
- Метод `re.findall` вернет список

*Если будет одна буква в верхнем регистре её тоже должно вытащить, но в таком случае можно отфильтровать список `words`, оставив в нем те, что имеют больше 1 символа*

Пример:

```
import re
deep_ocean = '''Окунь форель щУка Щука ФОрель Форель'''
nemo_pattern = r'\b([а-я]*[А-Я][а-я]*)\b'
words = re.findall(nemo_pattern, deep_ocean)
print(words)
# ['Окунь', 'щУка', 'Щука', 'Форель']
```